# symfony container: injected class's constructor not called

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

When I inject a service into another via constructor injection, the constructor of the injected class is not being called.
Has anyone an explanation for this. What am I overlooking?

I created this little sample for demonstration purposes:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    foo.A:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\A

    foo.B:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\B
        arguments:
            a: "@foo.A"
```

**Class A:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle;

class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "constructing A\n";
    }
}
```

**Class B:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle;

class B
{
    public function __construct($a)
    {
        echo "constructing B\n";
    }
}
```

**Testcode:**

```
echo "\nTest A ----------------------\n";
$this->getContainer()->get('foo.A');

echo "\nTest B ----------------------\n";
$this->getContainer()->get('foo.B');
```

**Output:**

Test A ----------------------
constructing A

Test B ----------------------
constructing B

When retrieving 'foo.B' I'd expect that also A's constructor would be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've called `$this->getContainer()->get('foo.A');` before `$this->getContainer()->get('foo.B');` there is already instance of `class A` so it's not created again.

Try to call only `$this->getContainer()->get('foo.B');` and you'll get output of both constructors

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what was happening. I wasn't considering that a service is only instantiated once. Thanks a lot.